# MS-Teams webhook: specify channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm looking for a way to post within a channel using a webhook (we do that on slack easily, but I couldn't find anything accurate with ms-teams).

I was hopping something like this :

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"text": "Hello World", "channel": "test"}' https://outlook.office.com/webhook/url...

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Incoming Webhooks are *already* channel-specific in Teams, so there's no need/no option to do this. See the docs here for instance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook#add-an-incoming-webhook-to-a-teams-channel